# How to get the properties from object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to handle a callback data from ajax and having a problem looping the data.

I have

```
data.prototype.handleReturnData = function(data) {

}
```

`data` is an object which contains 4 objects. Each object has a `test` and `test2` property.

How do I get those properties?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    alert(data[i].test);
    alert(data[i].test2);
}
```

Comment: Not quite right. I can alert(data[i].test) and it alert the code of the function. If we wanted only properties or did not know the names of said properties we could not do this.

Comment: @ars265 Yes but that is not what the question asks for. If it asked for getting the prop values without knowing the props, then I would have given a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try accessing your values with `data[0]['test']`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(yourobject);
```

This will get all the property names which you can then use to cycle through or pick your property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-in loop:

```
for (var prop in data) {
    if( data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // 'prop' refers to the property name
        // do something with data[prop] or data[prop].test
    }
}
```

The purpose of the `hasOwnProperty` check is to exclude inherited properties, which you probably aren't interested in. Some documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in